# Potion effect never wears out

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

I am writing a mod for Minecraft (in Java, duh) and want to apply a random potion effect like this:

```java
    private static Effect[] poss_effects = new Effect[]{
        Effects.SPEED,
        Effects.SLOWNESS,
        Effects.HASTE,
        Effects.MINING_FATIGUE,
        Effects.STRENGTH,
        Effects.INSTANT_HEALTH,
        Effects.INSTANT_DAMAGE,
        Effects.JUMP_BOOST,
        Effects.NAUSEA,
        Effects.REGENERATION,
        Effects.RESISTANCE,
        Effects.FIRE_RESISTANCE,
        Effects.WATER_BREATHING,
        Effects.INVISIBILITY,
        Effects.BLINDNESS,
        Effects.NIGHT_VISION,
        Effects.HUNGER,
        Effects.WEAKNESS,
        Effects.POISON,
        Effects.WITHER,
        Effects.HEALTH_BOOST,
        Effects.ABSORPTION,
        Effects.SATURATION,
        Effects.GLOWING,
        Effects.LEVITATION,
        Effects.LUCK,
        Effects.UNLUCK,
        Effects.SLOW_FALLING,
        Effects.CONDUIT_POWER,
        Effects.DOLPHINS_GRACE,
        Effects.BAD_OMEN,
        Effects.HERO_OF_THE_VILLAGE
    };
    
    private long prev_milli = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @Override
    public ActionResult<ItemStack> onItemRightClick(World worldIn, PlayerEntity playerIn, Hand handIn) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.prev_milli >= 60000) {
            Effect to_apply = poss_effects[(int) (Math.random() * poss_effects.length)];
            int duration = (int) (Math.random() * 15 * 20);
            int amplifier = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
            playerIn.addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(to_apply, duration, amplifier));
            this.prev_milli = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        return super.onItemRightClick(worldIn, playerIn, handIn);
    }
```

However, when the timer ticks down to zero on the potion effect, the effect stays there with the timer at `0:00`. The *first* time I right-click it, I get two potion effects: one that works properly and only lasts for the given amount of time and one that has the problem described previously. All subsequent right-clicks produce the latter.

When I do this:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean hitEntity(ItemStack stack, LivingEntity target, LivingEntity attacker) {
        target.addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.WITHER, 60, 2));
        target.setHeadRotation((float) (Math.random() * 360), (int) (Math.random() * 180 - 90));
        
        return super.hitEntity(stack, target, attacker);
    }
```

the effect applies normally and runs out normally every time I hit an entity.

What's wrong?

Comment: Is it wanted to get 2 potion effects on the first click ?

Comment: @SamuelFyckes -- No, just one.

Comment: and what is the line "if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.prev_milli >= 60000)" for ?

Comment: @SamuelFyckes -- It makes a 60 second cooldown.

Comment: Is there a chance that the problem come from the fact that you are trying to interact on the client side instead of the server side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I haven't actually implemented a Minecraft Mod. This answer is a bit of speculation, based on some old tutorials.*

Your method `onItemRightClick` will be called twice. Once for the client, and once for the server. *And, this remains true in single player on modern Minecraft, given that it uses an internal server.*

On the other hand, `hitEntity` would run only on the server.

In `onItemRightClick`, you need to check [`world.isRemote`](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/sides/#worldisremote). More precisely, when `world.isRemote` is true, you are in the client (then you can play sound effects, and stuff), while the logic (applying a potion effect in this case) should run on the server (that is when `world.isRemote` is false).

As it stand, you get a real effect applied on the server, and a fake one applied on the client.

It appears that the fake effect keeps being applied while the real one isn't. It makes sense that it does not apply the real effect again, given the time out. And it also makes sense that it does not sync `prev_milli` between server and client. However that does not explain why it does not timeout on the client. On that part, I have no idea... But a suggestion: use `addChatMessage` (I think that is the method, should be on the player object) to show the value of `prev_milli` on the chat and see what you get. Show `world.isRemote` while you are at it. That should help debugging.

---

*Unless I'm all wrong about this. I also want to mention that I have seen many tutorials not call `super.onItemRightClick`, I don't know what difference it makes. To guess over my guess, removing it prevents `onItemRightClick` from running on the client.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll check it out and get back to you.

Comment: But also, the "real" effect only applies the first time I right-click, not subsequent times. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I don't know, my suspicions are with the cool down. That is, the server saying the cool down is not over but the client saying it is.

Comment: I just tried your solution, and it works! Thanks so much!